# Como aplicar um *ngFor em um array de objetos em Angular em que o nome varia?

Tags: angular, typescript

Possuo o seguinte array chamado `dadosRelatorio` que preciso de iterar no meu template, esse array eu consigo através de uma requisição do meu backend.

```
[{"id": 1,
  "name": "a",
  "class":[{
     "Inglês":[{
        "id": 1,
        "code": "teste"
     },
     {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "teste 2"
     }],
     "Espanhol":[{
        "id": 1,
        "code": "a"
     }]
   }]
}]
```

Como eu posso iterar os objetos dentro de class se eles possuem diferentes nomes? Ocasionalmente pode vir `"Inglês"`, ocasionalmente `"Espanhol"`, dentre outras linguas.

Geralmente eu faço o `*ngFor` passando o nome do objeto, mas nesse caso eu nao sei o nome do objeto porque ele varia:

```
<div *ngFor="let aluno of dadosRelatorio" class="div-aluno">
       <span>Aluno: {{ aluno.name }}</span>
       <div *ngFor="let classe of aluno.class">
          <div *ngFor="let idioma of classe. ???>

          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ai voce tem que mappear seu array para as chaves deles serem uma propriedade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o KeyValuePipe para ler as propriedades do objeto e fazer uma iteração. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

Classe:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  dadosRelatorio = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
    class: [{
      'Inglês': [{
        id: 1,
        code: "teste"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        code: "teste 2"
      }],
        Espanhol: [{
          id: 1,
          code: "a"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }];
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let aluno of dadosRelatorio">
  <span>Aluno: {{ aluno.name }}</span>
  <div *ngFor="let classItem of aluno.class">
    <div *ngFor="let idioma of classItem | keyvalue">
      {{idioma.key}}
      <div *ngFor="let item of idioma.value">
        {{item.id}} - {{item.code}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Resultado:

```
Aluno: a
Espanhol
1 - a
Inglês
1 - teste
2 - teste 2
```

Comment: Funcionou bem dessa forma

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa pegar a chave do objeto, no Angular você pode utilizar o `Object.keys`. Tente fazer algo mais ou menos assim.

```js
    Component({
    selector: 'app-myview',
    template: `<div *ngFor="let aluno of dadosRelatorio" class="div-aluno">
                    <span>Aluno: {{ aluno.name }}</span>
                    <div *ngFor="let classe of aluno.class">
                        <div *ngFor="let idioma of objectKeys(classe)">
                            {{idioma + ' : ' + classe[idioma]}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`
    })

export class MyComponent {
    objectKeys = Object.keys;
    items = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "a",
            "class":[
                {
                    "Inglês":[
                        {"id": 1,"code": "teste"},
                        {"id": 2,"code": "teste 2"}
                    ],
                    "Espanhol":[
                        {"id": 1,"code": "a"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    constructor(){}
}
```